# How to get custom post type data filter by custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

Struggle to get all the records mapped by custom taxonomies.
I have registered a custom post type i.e. job_post and custom taxonomy i.e. countries. I wanted to show all job posts (having job_title, job_location, and permalink to specific job post) which are filtered by Countries (i.e. India & USA). I had Mapped almost 10 job posts under the India category and 18 job posts under the USA category.

I have displayed the records through toggle tabs (i.e. India and USA). I can fetch only one record by each category through the below code:

```
<section class="container container_filter">
    <div class="filters filter-button-group">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <?php
                $terms= get_terms('countries');
                foreach($terms as $cat_term)
                { ?>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $cat_term->slug;?>"><?php echo $cat_term->name; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    
    <div class="tab-content">
    <?php
        global $post;
        $args= array('post_type'=> 'job_post', 'post_per_page' => -1);
        
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if($the_query->have_posts()):
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?> 
            <?php
            $termsArray= get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'countries');
            $term_id=$termsArray->id;
            foreach ($termsArray as $term){
                $termsSlug = $term->slug;
            }   
        ?>
            <div id="<?php echo $termsSlug;?>" class="tab-pane fade">
              <div class='col-md-6'>
                            <a class='job-card readmoreCustom' href='<?php the_permalink($term_id); ?>'>
                                <div class='content'>
                                    <h3 class='title'><?php echo get_the_title($term_id) ?></h3>
                                    <p class='job_location'><?php the_field('job_location'); ?></p>
                                </div>
                                <span class='more'>KNOW MORE<span class="readIcon"> &gt; </span></span>                                
                            </a>                
                    </div>
            </div>
        <?php   
     endwhile;
     wp_reset_query();
    ?> 
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php _e('Sorry, no jobs matches your criteria'); ?>
         
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

How can I fetch all the records from both categories under specific tabs? Help is appreciated.

Comment: The single job post assigned to both USA & India as well ? Or each job is assigned to only single country ?

Comment: I think you want to display post title then why are you passing $term_id ?. get_the_title($term_id); only this much is enough get_the_title();......... $term_id=$termsArray->id; this should be like this $term_id=$termsArray[0]->term_id;........ I've added answer please check if that works

Comment: @ShaikhAejazAhmed Yes, I want to assign each job to a single category and I have updated $term_id=$termsArray[0]->term_id; and also kept get_the_title(); only, still getting the same result. I got one job in India tab and one in USA tab as I want to retrieve all the jobs under specific category.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="container container_filter">
    <div class="filters filter-button-group">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <?php
                $terms= get_terms('countries');
                foreach($terms as $cat_term)
                { ?>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#<?php echo $cat_term->slug;?>"><?php echo $cat_term->name; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    
    <div class="tab-content">
    <?php
        global $post;
        $args= array('post_type'=> 'job_post', 'post_per_page' => -1);
        
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if($the_query->have_posts()):
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?> 
            <?php
            $termsArray= get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'countries');
            $term_id=$termsArray[0]->term_id;
            foreach ($termsArray as $term){
                $termsSlug = $term->slug;
            }   
        ?>
            <div id="<?php echo $termsSlug;?>" class="tab-pane fade">
              <div class='col-md-6'>
                            <a class='job-card readmoreCustom' href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'>
                                <div class='content'>
                                    <h3 class='title'><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    <p class='job_location'><?php the_field('job_location'); ?></p>
                                </div>
                                <span class='more'>KNOW MORE<span class="readIcon"> &gt; </span></span>                                
                            </a>                
                    </div>
            </div>
        <?php   
     endwhile;
     wp_reset_query();
    ?> 
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php _e('Sorry, no jobs matches your criteria'); ?>
         
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

The below loop is fine if the post is in only 1 country but if it's in multiple counties the loop should be closed after div

```
foreach ($termsArray as $term){
                $termsSlug = $term->slug;
            }
```

Comment: Hey, I tried above code it's showing all posts not one